# Provide different abstract class to be extended in vendor

Tags: php, laravel, extend

A vendor package I'm using has an abstract class that is extended throughout the package, I am trying to add a trait to the abstract class so it is used by each class that extends the abstract class.

What it looks like

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
}
```

and

```
class A extends AbstractClass {
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend a vendor class directly by modifying its source code (actually, you could but it's a **very** bad practice). Depending on the context, you have 3 ways to achieve something similar:

**1** - Classic inheritance with some methods overriden. Do not forget contracts which allow you to substitute some Laravel classes with yours by implementing these contracts and customize dependency injection.

**2** - Using a trait when **1** is not efficient. For example Laravel paginators, `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` and `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`. If you want to extend them with same functionalities, **1** asks 2 identic implementations whereas **2** needs only 1 implementation.

**3** - The only way to extend without implementing custom classes is the use of `macro`/`mixin` methods from `Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable`. But it's only possible if the base class used this trait.

Comment: 1- I would prefer to not IoC swap each non-abstract class individually 2- This wouldn't work as there are no implements only extends. 3 - The class doesn't use that unfortunately. For clarification I'm trying to add a trait (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/tests/Support/SupportCapsuleManagerTraitTest.php#L14) to an abstract class in a vendor package.